# How to clear cache and all private data in IE8 Using python

Tags: python, caching, internet-explorer-8, pywin32

I've been trying to find a way to clear IE8 Cache and all the private data using Python! But couldn't! Currently I'm using "Pythoncom/win32com.client" modules, I just want to clear IE8 data not other browsers! or if there is a way to delete IE8 data files that it save?

Thanks

Comment: -1: The question is not really about programming, it is about how to delete IE cache without using IE.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Why on earth would you want use a programming language to clear the cache of a browser.

Comment: I've been making a program of search and its limited because of number of tries! I don't wanna use other libraries! that's why I need to!